# C# WPF TextBox в Template не изменяет Text

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

Есть TextBox в Control Template ListBoxItem

```
<TextBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding (extensions:DetectorExtension.Data), RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}}" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="16" Foreground="Black" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Background="White" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0"/> // выше xmlns:extensions="clr-namespace:Test.Extensions"
```

и его Text биндится к Attached Property

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty DataProperty =
  DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Data", typeof(string),
      typeof(DetectorExtension), new PropertyMetadata(null));
public static string GetData(DependencyObject obj)
    => (string)obj.GetValue(DataProperty);

public static void SetData(DependencyObject obj, string value)
    => obj.SetValue(DataProperty, value);
```

ListBox:

```
<ListBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" SelectionMode="Extended" ItemsSource="{Binding DetectorsViewModel}">
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{DynamicResource DetectorControlTemplate}"/>
            <Setter Property="extensions:DetectorExtension.Name" Value="{Binding Name}"/>
            <Setter Property="extensions:DetectorExtension.Data" Value="{Binding Data}"/>
        </Style>
   </ListBox.Resources>
</ListBox>
```

DetectorsViewModel:

```
private ObservableCollection<DetectorViewModel> detectorsViewModel;
public ObservableCollection<DetectorViewModel> DetectorsViewModel {
  get => this.detectorsViewModel;
  set => this.detectorsViewModel = value;
}
```

и Data в DetectorViewModel:

```
protected string data;

public string Data {
   get => this.data;
   set => SetProperty(ref this.data, value);
}
```

Биндинг работает и string показываеться в Text, и если изменять его програмно все тоже нормально, но если езменять в программе TextBox то данные не изменяються в View Model, ничего не происходит

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По умолчанию, свойства зависимости используют одностороннюю привязку, поэтому надо или явно создавать свойство сразу с двухсторонней привязкой:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty DataProperty =
    DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Data", typeof(string), typeof(DetectorExtension),
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));
```

Или указывать эту двухстороннюю привязку в свойстве:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding (extensions:DetectorExtension.Data), Mode=TwoWay,
                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}}" ...
```

Первый способ в данном случае предпочтительнее.