# Управление привязкой внутри шаблона

Tags: wpf, .net

У меня есть `TreeView` c тремя элементами, каждый из которых привязан к своей коллекции.

```
<TreeView Name="fileList">
    <TreeViewItem ItemsSource="{Binding Collection1}" Header="List1" Style="{DynamicResource TreeViewItemStyle}"                          
                  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TreeViewItemTemplate1}"/>
    <TreeViewItem ItemsSource="{Binding Collection2}" Header="List2" Style="{DynamicResource TreeViewItemStyle}"
                  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TreeViewItemTemplate2}"/>
    <TreeViewItem ItemsSource="{Binding Collection3}" Header="List3" Style="{DynamicResource TreeViewItemStyle}"                          
                  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TreeViewItemTemplate3}"/>
</TreeView>
```

Каждый `TreeViewItem` имеет свой шаблон, но стиль у всех один.

```
<Style x:Key="TreeViewItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="19" Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="4"/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <ToggleButton x:Name="Expander" ClickMode="Press" IsChecked="{Binding IsExpanded, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Style="{StaticResource ExpandCollapseToggleStyle}" Margin="5,0,5,0"/>

                    <Border x:Name="Bd" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="TemplateBinding Background}" Grid.Column="1" Padding={TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" Style={StaticResource CheckBoxStyle}">
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_Header" ContentSource="Header" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
                        </CheckBox>
                    </Border>

                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Grid.Column="2"/>

                    <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsHost" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Но как для каждого элемента сделать разную привязку данных внутри шаблона? Мне нужно, чтобы свойство `IsChecked` элемента `CheckBox`, в котором содержится `ContentPresenter`, для каждого элемента связывалось с разными свойствами из VM. Как это можно сделать не используя для каждого `TreeViewItem` отдельный стиль?

Comment: Это стандартная задача для Attached Property

Comment: Смотрите этот ответ: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/852624/218063

Comment: Получилось у вас?

Comment: @АндрейNOP, получилось, спасибо! Только там нюанс -- Text="{TemplateBinding c:MyButtonExtension.Text}" не работает в две стороны, пришлось остановиться на простом Binding

Comment: Да, TemplateBinding специально оптимизирован для односторонней привязки (см. [документацию](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/templatebinding-markup-extension#remarks)), поэтому только обычный Binding, для упрощения в нем можно еще написать `RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}` вместо FindAncestor. Ну и AP можно сделать по умолчанию с двухсторонней привязкой, как здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/899346/218063